# ¿Por qué me sirve cargarDatos pero cargarFacturas (que es la misma función pero con otros valores) no me sirve?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo estas dos funciones en **JS**, estoy usando **jQuery** y estoy usando la **BD del navegador**. La cosa es que en la segunda función no me trae los objetos porque dice que `result.rows.nombre(i)` no es una función. En cambio en la primera función (*cargarDatos*) sí me sirve bien. Justo antes que me salte el error con `console.log` me doy cuenta que sí me trae el objeto y sí tiene un tamaño y todo pero al parecer no puedo acceder a sus propiedades para desestructurarlo.

```
function cargarDatos(){
    $("#listaProductos").children().remove();
    db.transaction(function(transaction){
        var sql="SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY id ASC";
        transaction.executeSql(sql, undefined, function(transaction, result){
            console.log(result.rows.item)
            if(result.rows.item){
                $("#listaProductos").append('<tr><th>Código</th><th>Producto</th><th>Cantidad</th><th>Precio</th><th></th><th></th></tr>')
                for(var i=0; i<result.rows.length; i++){
                    var row=result.rows.item(i);
                    var item=row.item;
                    var cantidad=row.cantidad;
                    var id=row.id;
                    var precio=row.precio;
                    $("#listaProductos").append('<tr id="fila'+id+'" class="Reg_A'+id+'"> <td><span class="miId">A'+
                    id+'</span></td><td><span>'+
                    item+'</span></td><td><span>'+
                    cantidad+'</span></td><td><span>'+
                    precio+' USD$ </span></td><td><button type="button" id="A'+
                    id+'" onclick="eliminarRegistro()"><i class="fas fa-backspace"></button></i></td></tr>');
                }
            }else{
                $("#listaProductos").append('<tr><td colspan="5" align="center">No existen los productos.</td></tr>');

            }

        }, function(transaction, err){
            alert('Oh no, algo salió mal :c '+ err.message);
        }
        )
    })  
}
```

Y esta, que es la misma, es la que no me sirve, no entra al `if` porque dice que `result.rows.nombre` es `undefined`, pero si imprimo `result.rows` sí me muestra el objeto (vean la última imagen):

```
function cargarFacturas(){
    $("#listaFacturas").children().remove();
    db.transaction(function(transaction){
        var sql="SELECT * FROM facturas ORDER BY id ASC";
        transaction.executeSql(sql, undefined, function(transaction, result){
            console.log(result.rows.nombre)
            if(result.rows.nombre){
                console.log(result.rows.length)
                $("#listaFacturas").append('<tr><th>#</th><th>Cliente</th><th>Total</th><th>Fecha</th><th>Estado</th><th>Tipo de pago</th><th></th></tr>')
                for(var i=0; i<result.rows.length; i++){
                    
                    var row=result.rows.nombre(i);
                    alert('itwork')
                    var item=row.nombre;
                    var cantidad=row.total;
                    var id=row.id;
                    var fecha=row.fecha;
                    var estado=row.estado;
                    var tpago=row.tpago;
                    $("#listaFacturas").append('<tr id="fila'+id+'" class="Reg_F'+id+'"> <td><span class="miId2">F'+
                    id+'</span></td><td><span>'+
                    item+'</span></td><td><span>'+
                    cantidad+'USD$ </span></td><td><span>'+
                    fecha+' </span></td><td><span>'+
                    estado+' </span></td><td><span>'+
                    tpago+' </span></td><td><button type="button" id="F'+
                    id+'" onclick="eliminarFacturas()"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart">Pagar</i></button></i></td></tr>');
                }
            }else{
                $("#listaFacturas").append('<tr><td colspan="5" align="center">No existen los productos.</td></tr>');

            }

        }, function(transaction, err){
            alert('Oh no, algo salió mal2 :c '+ err.message);
        }
        )
    })  
}
```

Los valores de la BD:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto me sale si imprimo `result.rows`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por lo que veo, en el primer ejemplo sí funciona porque la instrucción

```
var row=result.rows.item(i);
```

retorna un objeto de tipo *row* y desde allí se obtienen los datos, por ejemplo `row.nombre`.

Sin embargo en el ejemplo que falla estás llamando a

```
var row=result.rows.nombre(i);
```

y el error que informa es que aquella no es una función, y por ende no puede conseguir los datos para el resto de la función.

Por lo tanto en la función *cargarFacturas()*
la línea

```
var row=result.rows.nombre(i);
```

debe ser reemplazada por

```
var row=result.rows.item(i);
```

Comment: Disculpa amigo, pero no entendí muy bien. Entonces qué estoy haciendo mal? Si hago lo mismo en ambos lados solo que con diferentes valores. Qué debería cambiar? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: en el segundo caso debiese quedar. igual que el primero.

var row=result.rows.item(i);

Comment: Pero son dos tablas diferentes, item es de la tabla productos y nombre es de la tabla facturas. Sí sirvió amigo. Muchas gracias. Pero me puedes explicar porqué? jaja es que no entiendo.

Comment: No confundas la columna _item_ con el **método** _item_... Revisa la API de Web SQL :)

Comment: Muchas gracias.